# How to create a sitemap with XML sitemap module?

Tags: xml-sitemap

I understand that [XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module is the near-standard way to create a sitemap for a Drupal site.

The [Readme file](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/xmlsitemap/-/blob/8.x-1.x/README.txt) isn't clear to me about how to create a sitemap.

> - Install as you would normally install a contributed Drupal module. Visit
>   https://www.drupal.org/node/1897420 for further information.
> - Once XML Sitemap is installed and enabled, you can adjust the settings for your
>   site's sitemap at admin/config/search/xmlsitemap. Your can view your site's
>   sitemap at http://yoursite.com/sitemap.xml.
> - It is highly recommended that you have clean URLs enabled for this module.

Okay but what should I do in actuality?

### What I have tried to get it work

I went to `admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/entities/settings` and check-marked the entities I want to create a sitemap by and saved the page.

I then went to `/admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/rebuild` and had an option *Select which link types you would like to rebuild* but the list container is **empty** (i.e. there is nothing to select).

When navigating to https://yoursite.com/sitemap.xml I get only one row with `http://default/he`. This also happens after I **rebuild** the map.

### My question

How to create a sitemap with XML sitemap module?

Comment: In what way is the module not working? Is there not a response at `/sitemap.xml`.

Comment: XML Sitemap is not the "standard" for Drupal 8+.  For the week of September 11, 2022, it has 43,906 installs for 8+, while Simple XML Sitemap module has 87,605 installs, making it twice as popular.

Comment: They said “near-standard”.

Comment: @cilefen it is not working in the sense that when navigating to yoursite.com/sitemap.xml I get only one row with `http://default/he`. This also happens after I rebuild the map.

Comment: Question edited to indicate what I have tried exactly.

Comment: Did you see the Installing and Configuring Guide? https://www.drupal.org/node/264650

Comment: @cilefen Just now thank you